# Transitive action of $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, symmetric-groups

Let $a$ and $n$ be positive integers with $a \leqslant n$. Is there a transitive action of $S_n$ on a set $A$ of $\binom{n}{a}$ elements?

My attempt was to fix a set $\{1, \cdots, n\}$ and consider the set $C$ of all choices $\{i_1, \cdots, i_a\}$.

However, if I just let $S_n$ act by $\sigma(\{i_1, \cdots, i_a\}) = \{\sigma(i_1), \cdots, \sigma(i_a)\}$, it will not be a group action as it is not closed.

I could not however think about any other actions.

I moved on trying to prove there is no such an action but get stuck.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand why you think the action you have described is not a group action. It looks fine to me (assuming that $C$ is intended to be the set of all subsets of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ with $a$ elements).

Comment: Why don't you think it's closed?

Comment: I did not sleep well last night. Please ignore this post.